# Retrieving the Selected multiple select values

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I need to have multiple values selected when I call that LoadDropDown function. But its not working.... Please suggest how to get multiple options selected.

```
<td>Select Profession:</td>
<td>
<select name="selectcontent_profession" id="selectcontent_profession" multiple>
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="10">Student</option>
<option value="201">Lecturer</option>
<option value="333">Head Of Department</option>
<option value="421">Principal</option>
<option value="523">Chairman</option>
<option value="667">Management</option>
<option value="784">Placement Officer</option>
</select>
</td>

<%  
String s1= "10,333,421,523";
String[]  array = s1.split(",");
%>

<script >
function LoadDropDown()
{
<%for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){%>

document.getElementById("selectcontent_profession").value ="<%= array[i]%>";

<%}%>
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare the select's multiple selection option as follows:

```
<select name="selectcontent_profession" id="selectcontent_profession" multiple="multiple">
```

And your function should be like this:

```
var fld = document.getElementById('selectcontent_profession');
for(var i=0;i<fld.options.length;i++){
for(var j=0;j<array1.length;j++){
    if(fld.options[i].value==array1[j])fld.options[i].selected=true;
    }
}
```

You are trying to get the value of the dropdown whereas you have to set it to selected.

Comment: :Your method would be suitable if i used indexes. But here i wanna use values. The String array contains the values of the options.
If i change any value inside the option to 25. 
Since there are only 7 indexes the value wont be selected.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you are trying to achieve? Why would you change your value for options?

Comment: Edited my answer. But still I feel you should check if you are going to change the value for option in real.

Comment: Thanks... This will do it :)
I was using the same approach but forgot to put the "==" sign correctly in if loop. 
And over that ur approach in ur previous solution was wrong.
The array stores the values .And you were assigning values to selected Index

Answer (score 0):

You have to `add` the options like

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "<%= array[i]%>";
option.value = "<%= array[i]%>";
 document.getElementById("selectcontent_profession").options
                                                       .add(option);
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is of selecting multiple values. Options is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("selectcontent_profession").options[<%=array[i]%>].defaultSelected =true;
```

Use this statement in the loop.

Comment: Your method would be suitable if i used indexes. But here i wanna use values. The String array contains the values of the options.
If i change any value inside the option to 25. 
Since there are only 7 indexes the value wont be selected.